# how can we get the output of a veriable on each step-size in RK4stepsize method?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, fortran77

I am using Fortran 77 in Intel Fortran. I want to ask that how can we take the output of a variable at each step size using the RK4-step size method
I have different subroutines in the code. IF we calculate the root of a variable by Bernt's method in another subroutine and then for that root we want to take output at each time step using rk4 adaptive stepsize method how can we do?

for example

```
call adaptivestep_size(x,t,t+dt,epx,dt,hmin,nok,nbad,ad,bsstep,
 &pwE,pwB,gamma,ep,zlamda)
```

here zlamda is the subroutine which is calculating the root of desired variable by brent's method in another subroutine as,

```
    SUBROUTINE zlamda(lamdaroot)
      INTEGER N,NBMAX
      REAL X1,X2
      PARAMETER(N=100,NBMAX=20,X1=0.0,X2=3.141592/2.)        ! take X2=pi/2 to find smallest root only out of multiple roots
      INTEGER i,nb
      REAL zbrent,root,tol,xb1(NBMAX),xb2(NBMAX)
      EXTERNAL zbrak,fzlamda
      REAL eL,z,fzlamda,lamdaroot,lamda
      COMMON /flamda/ eL,z
      nb=NBMAX
      call zbrak(fzlamda,X1,X2,N,xb1,xb2,nb)
      do 200 i=1,nb
        tol=(1.0e-6)*(xb1(i)+xb2(i))/2.0
        lamdaroot=zbrent(fzlamda,xb1(i),xb2(i),tol)       ! here you get latitude, "lamdaroot" in radian, from given "z"
 
 200  continue
  
      return
      END
  
      FUNCTION fzlamda(lamda)  
      REAL fzlamda,z,eL,lamda
      COMMON /flamda/ eL,x(3,1)    ! eL (normalized L value), z are supposed to be provided. Then, fzlamda is a function of lamda only
  
  
      lamda=9.*3.1415926535/180.0
      
      fzlamda=0.5*sin(lamda)*sqrt(1.+3.*sin(lamda)**2)+(0.5/sqrt(3.))
     +    *log(abs(sqrt(3.)*sin(lamda)+sqrt(1.+3.*sin(lamda)**2)))
     +    -abs(x(3,1))/4685.0    ! taking abs(z) means: lamda increases from equator as abs(z) increases 
      return
      
      END
```

now actually the `lamdaroot` is the variable for which I want to take output at each time step so how would I set the subroutine `zlamda` which will give me output thought the whole calculations

Comment: Are you looking to write the values to a file or maybe view them in on screen? If so, using a ```write``` statement might be what you need.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
its not just writing the variables which i have already done I want to put that written values of a variable in another function in which both variables are related to each other like if one changed the other must be chnage but in my case one is cahnging but another is not say z is changing and lambda is not while they both have to change their values during the calculations

Comment: More information is needed. If I understand well, you have a system of differential equations and you want the value of the functions involved at a specific time determined by the root you calculate. But then I am not quite sure how that root is affected by the solution of the differential equations. There are many possible answers depending on the nature of the problem. A simplified example of what you are trying to do will help people providing a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,yes you got the point

Sir my question is that I have some variable outputs and say z is variable and have output of z in txt form 

and from the brent's method, I want to calculate lambda(another variable) and the function containing lambda is depending on the z. so how can I put z value in the function dependent on z so that I can get the value of lambda correctly?

Comment: FUNCTION fzlamda(lamda)  
      REAL fzlamda,z,eL,lamda
      COMMON /flamda/ eL,z,x(3,1)     
    !  eL=4685.0
 25     if(rt.gt.05) then
          goto 20
      z=x(3,1)
      
 20   lamda=9*3.1415926535/180.0
       else 
       goto 25
       endif
      fzlamda=0.5*sin(lamda)*sqrt(1.+3.*sin(lamda)**2)+(0.5/sqrt(3.))
     +    *log(abs(sqrt(3.)*sin(lamda)+sqrt(1.+3.*sin(lamda)**2)))
     +    -abs(z)/4685.0                                              ! taking abs(z) means: lamda increases from equator as abs(z) increases 
      return
      END

Comment: where z is z=x(3,1) and getting txt result as 

 if(rt.eq.0)then
          write(1,1000)t/(2*pi),(x(i,1),i=1,3),lamdaroot,(x(i,2),i=1,2),
     &(x(i,3),i=1,2),alpha*180.d0/pi,kew,deta
         
      else
          write(1,1000)t/(2*pi),(x(i,1),i=1,3),lamdaroot,(x(i,2),i=1,2),
     &(x(i,3),i=1,2),alpha*180.d0/pi,kew,deta
      endif

Comment: welcome, please take the [tour] to se how to use this site. Do not use comments for important information, especially not for code, [edit] your question instead. Read also [ask].

Comment: To reiterate one of @VladimirF's points - don't put code in comments if you want people to read it.

Comment: alright,I will do that